# sql query to laravel query with sub query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

pls help how to make right this sql, cant make right with two select and RAND

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `galleries` 
               WHERE domain_id = 13 AND is_deleted = 0 
               ORDER BY galleries.id DESC LIMIT 30) q 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

to like this

```
$galleries = DB::table('galleries')->select( DB::raw('galleries.*') )
            ->where( 'domain_id', 13 )
            ->where( 'is_deleted', 0 ) ...
```

Comment: Haven't tried but this might help you http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT * FROM `galleries`
WHERE domain_id = 13 
AND is_deleted = 0 
ORDER BY id DESC,RAND()
LIMIT 30
```

And in laravel something like

```
$galleries = DB::table('galleries')
            ->select( DB::raw('galleries.*') )
            ->where( 'domain_id', 13 )
            ->where( 'is_deleted', 0 )
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
```

Or get your results from above query without applying `->orderByRaw('RAND()')` and do [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
$galleries = $galleries->toArray(); 
shuffle($galleries);
```

Comment: @ARUNMadathil I can't say for sure `inRandomOrder()` will work

Comment: this query dont work
SELECT * FROM `galleries`
WHERE domain_id = 13 
AND is_deleted = 0 
ORDER BY id DESC,RAND()
LIMIT 30
I tried in mysql, RAND dont works
and in laravel dont work too...


p. s. Laravel version 5.1

Comment: @AlexTMZ you can try another approach using `shuffle` in php get your desired data and then apply this